# zombie process remove without wait C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I've got a child process which just `exit(0)`. It became zombie. Is there way to remove it without `wait` or `waitpid` in parent process?

```
R+  ./server //parent
R+  ./server //child
Z+  (server) //child zombie
```

Comment: Not sure how this is a C post.  Perhaps because Unix was created in C?  :)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `wait` or `waitpid`?

Comment: because `wait` will stop parent process, until child exit.

Comment: maybe exist the way to run parent without stop with `wait`?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan This might be tagged C, because answer is expected to include C code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest is to make SIGCHLD ignored in the parent:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

After that, exiting child processes will just cleanly go away without needing to be waited on.

Note: This a bit of a quick&dirty approach, and assumes that you simply do not care about exit status of the child process, or about when it exits. If you do care, as you probably should in a real robust application, then see the other answer, about creating a proper signal handler function.

Addition: This is not universal in Unixes, but works at least on Linux. According to [an UNIX FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-13.html), it is undefined behaviour in POSIX. [This Mac OS X man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html) suggests that this behaviour was introduced in FreeBSD 5.0, and works on OS X, for example.

Comment: Wouldn't the children processes go away (without being zombies) only when the parent process exits? In other words, aren't they zombies till the parent exits? I would imagine the parent could still `waitpid` them even when ignoring the `SIGCHLD` signal, so the kernel has to zombify the children process (but I may be wrong, because I did not test that).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Added a paragraph and a link explaining more. But when it works, then exited/terminated child process really just goes away, no zombie, not possible to wait.

Comment: But does the child process goes away immediately, or only when the parent process exits?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not 100% sure if it is *immediately* or if there is a delay (might even be different in different supporting OSes), but it will go away quickly without being a resource leak, and does not depend on parent exiting. There would not be much point in the whole mechanism, otherwise...

Answer (score 7):

You could catch the `SIGCHLD` signal (e.g. using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) etc...). Be careful, very few functions are safely callable from a signal handler. Read several times [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). A good thing to do inside a signal handler is to just set some `volatile sigatomic_t` flag (which you would test later, *outside* of the signal handler, e.g. in some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)). Or you could, at initialization time, setup a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (to your own process) and write a few bytes on it in your signal handler (and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) the read end elsewhere), as [suggested by Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

And [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) can be told to not stop with `WNOHANG`

If you never wait for your child process, it will become [zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It has a good chapter on processes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the double `fork` technique:

Create a child child process. And terminate the child process immediately after that.
In this way the child child process will go under the `init` process. The `init` process will automatically wait outs the child child process when it exits.

This does not remove `waitpid`, because the parent must wait end of the child process. 
Because the life time of the child process is always minimal, you can call `waitpid` from the parent without long blocking.

See [this article](http://thinkiii.blogspot.fi/2009/12/double-fork-to-avoid-zombie-process.html) for more information.